# what are the correct setting for the .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

My hosting company **deleted** my **.htaccess file** (they thought they were helping me resolve a different problem). Now - my .htaccess has the following info only:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

I found the ORIGINAL .htaccess file in my old backups but it has the following info:

> adjust memory limit
>
> ```
> php_value memory_limit 64M
> php_value memory_limit 256M
> php_value max_execution_time 18000
> ```

I changed hosting since then I have the following for hosting now:

**VPS, CPU 8 Cores, RAM 6144 MB**

*What do you think the php_value memory_limits should be and the php_value max_execution_time?*

Answer (score 2):

For all projects on Apache I'm using the following values

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value max_execution_time 180
```

From experience I know 256M is enough to run most indexers and other resource heavy backend tools / imports but per project it might vary.

If you need more .htaccess settings, I've placed the one I use on every project on github https://github.com/sandermangel/magento-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

php_value memory_limit 64M: You can change this value up to 128MB depending on your needs. This value should be kept to the minimum necessary to run your application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you just want to know about php settings on htaccess or need more help to rebuild all your htaccess settings for a fast and secure magento shop.
If only the first case, recommended PHP memory limit is for Magento is no less than 256Mb (preferably 512). 
You can check it here [Magento System Requirements](https://magento.com/resources/previous-magento-system-requirements)